# How to reverse these commands in cmd?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, laptop, virtualbox, partitioning

I have some problem with Virtualbox and I found this [site](https://www.technewstoday.com/result-code-e_fail-0x80004005/#disable-device-guard-or-credential-guard) and it tells me to run these commands:

```
mountvol X: /s
copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:
mountvol X: /d
```

Now I changed my mind and I want to reverse these commands. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a new boot entry, the logical reversing
action would be to delete it.

Without testing, here is what I think is the command :

```
bcdedit /delete {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
```

It should be run in a Command Prompt (CMD) that is Run as Administrator.

As a precaution, ensure that you have an installation USB for
your Windows version with which you could boot if this command
will cause boot problems.

For more information see the article
[Delete Boot Menu Entry in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/delete-boot-menu-entry-in-windows-10/).